# Why loop is executing twice while writing to a file

Tags: python, file

I have 2 files `abc.txt`, `cde.txt`

The content of abc.txt is "This is abc file"
The content of cde.txt is "This is cde file"

I am trying to write to a file. But the content writing twice
Below is the code

```
in_files = ['abc.txt','cde.txt']
out_files = ['abc_output.txt','cde_output.txt']
read_dict = {}
for file in in_files:
    with open(file,'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
        read_dict[file] = lines
read_dict
for k,v in read_dict.items():
    for out in out_files: 
        with open(out,'w+') as write_file:
             for i in v:
                print(i)
```

Output

```
This is abc file
This is abc file
This is cde file
This is cde file
```

Expected

```
This is abc file
This is cde file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `print(i)` to `print('writing to', write_file, i)`, you'll see that the first time "*This is abc file*" is printed is for when you would write to *abc_output.txt* and the second time it is printed is for when you would output to *cde_output.txt*.

Your expected output will only show up once in each file. Is that what you are wanting, or do you want "*This is abc file*" to only get outputted to *abc_output.txt* and "*This is cde file*" to only get outputted to *cde_output.txt*? If that's the case you would want to do something like this:

```
in_files = ['abc.txt','cde.txt']
out_files = ['abc_output.txt','cde_output.txt']
read_dict = {}
for in_f, out_f in zip(in_files, out_files):
    with open(in_f,'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
    with open(out_f,'w+') as write_file:
         #write_file.writelines(lines)
        print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening simply because you run the outer loop twice (one time for each out file) and it causes total 4 runs instead of two.

```
read_dict = {'file1':'abc file', 'file2':'cde file'}
out_files = ['out1', 'out2']

for k,v in read_dict.items():
    for out in out_files:
        print(k, v)
```

Run this code above, this generates exactly what you get in the output files.

Answer (score 0):

The last loop you had added was unnecessary and the one before that was causing it to run twice because it was nested under the `for k,v in read_dict.items()` loop...

```
    in_files = ['abc.txt','cde.txt']
    out_files = ['abc_output.txt','cde_output.txt']
    read_dict = {}
    for file in in_files:
     with open(file,'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
        read_dict[file] = lines
read_dict
for k,v in read_dict.items():
    for out in out_files: 
      with open(out,'w+') as write_file:
            print(v)
            break;
```